# Average value of range of vector elements

Tags: matlab

I have a huge amount of data in MATLAB (350695x5). 
An example is like this:

```
z = [
1.79    0.16    0.16    21.39   21.50
1.83    0.16    0.16    21.39   22.40
1.92    0.16    0.16    21.39   22.00
2.07    0.16    0.16    21.39   22.00
2.36    0.15    0.15    21.39   21.08
2.96    0.13    0.13    21.39   21.04
3.21    0.13    0.13    21.39   23.00
3.72    0.12    0.12    21.39   24.00
3.87    0.11    0.11    21.39   21.39
4.14    0.10    0.10    21.39   22.00
4.14    0.10    0.10    21.39   21.50
4.16    0.10    0.10    21.39   21.39]
```

and I need to sort it in the following way: 
based on 1 column from 1-2, 2-3, 3-4 
and find mean values in the range (0-1, 1-2, 2-3, 3-4) for 2,3,4 columns

the result should look like this:

```
1   0.16    0.16    21.39   21.97
2   0.15    0.15    21.39   21.49
3   0.12    0.12    21.39   22.68
4   0.10    0.10    21.39   21.63
```

The problem is that I cannot sort it in a proper way.

The part of the solution can be described by

```
[ii jj] = ndgrid(z(:,1)+1,1:size(z,2)-1) %should sort first column from 0-1,1-2, 2-3, 3-4
z23 = z(:,2:end) 
out = [unique(z(:,1)),accumarray([ii(:),jj(:)],z23(:),[],@mean)], %find mean value
```

Comment: So what is your question? You didn't ask any. Also please read [ask], as we'd like to see some effort from your side into solving this, specifically the code you already tried. [edit] your question to contain a [mcve].

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
idx = floor(z(:, 1));
sub = [idx z(:, 2:5)];
[xx, yy] = ndgrid(idx, 1:size(sub, 2));
out = accumarray([xx(:) yy(:)], sub(:), [], @mean)

out =

    1.0000    0.1600    0.1600   21.3900   21.9667
    2.0000    0.1467    0.1467   21.3900   21.3733
    3.0000    0.1200    0.1200   21.3900   22.7967
    4.0000    0.1000    0.1000   21.3900   21.6300
```

Results don't match exactly with yours. I'm not sure I understand exactly what you wanted, but the code I wrote calculates the average on ranges `1 <= x < 2`, `2 <= x < 3`, and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Use logical indexing to find the values in `z` where a certain range applies, e.g.:

```
i01 = (z >= 0) & (z < 1);  % Find logical indices
z01 = z(i01);  % Get values from 0 up to 1 (but not including 1)
```

Then, calculation of the mean is easy: `mu_z01 = mean(z01);`. Of course, the same method can be applied to the other ranges from 1 to 2, 2 to 3, et cetera.

Comment: So you'd hand-copy the code for every conceivable range? Seems like a lot of work.

Comment: @Adriaan, of course not. An answer should not always completely answer the question, but guide the asker towards their goal. Every conceivable range can be programmed using a `for`-loop. This answer is by no means a complete answer to the question, but it answers part of it.